# How to extract a certain text from a string using Python

Tags: python

Consider I have a string in the format

`sampleapp-ABCD-1234-us-eg-123456789`. I need to extract the text `ABCD-1234`. Its more like I need `ABCD and then the numbers before the -`

Please let me know how can i do that

Comment: Can you please help @ManojKumar

Comment: If the number characters is fixed, then you can use string slicing.

Comment: No...it can vary @ManojKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use string.split(), so it would be:

```
string = 'sampleapp-ABCD-1234-us-eg-123456789'
example = string.split('-')
```

Then you can access 'abcd' and '1234' as example[1] and example[2] respectively. You can also join them back together into one string if needs be with string.join().

```
string = 'sampleapp-ABCD-1234-us-eg-123456789'
example = string.split('-')

newstring = ' '.join(example[1:3])
print (newstring)
```

You can also change the seperator, '-'.join would make it so the output is 'ABCD-1234' rather than 'ABCD 1234'.

Comment: I think should solve your problem.

Comment: can we get using regex ?

Comment: You could, but if the text you need is always going to be in the same position there's honestly no point.

Comment: can we make like the text ABCD and the the number before the next -, like that format ?

Comment: Do you mean so it's one string? Like 'ABCD-1234'? I'll add it to the answer above.

Comment: @wanderors please remember to select a correct answer if one worked for you, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex (Regular expression)
Here's the Python script you can use:

```py
import re

txt = "sampleapp-ABCD-1234-us-eg-123456789"
x = re.findall("([ABCD]+[-][0-9]+)", txt)
print(x)
```

More varied version:

```py
x = re.findall("([A-Z]{4}[-][0-9]+)", txt)
```

For more info about Regex you can learn it here: [regexr.com](https://regexr.com)

Hope this helps. Cheer!

Comment: It didnt work..

Comment: Can you show me the output?
I want to know why it didn't work.

Comment: It printed as []

Comment: Can I see the code?

Comment: x = re.findall("([GEST]+[-][0-9]+)", STRING)
            print("XXXXXXX")
            print(x)

String provided was JustTrial-GEST-1234-ty-eg-123456789

Comment: The code that you give works just fine. I'll give you the more varied version.

Comment: Sure...that will be of great help

Comment: I've already edited my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```
txt = "sampleapp-ABCD-1234-us-eg-123456789"
abcd = txt[10:14]
digits = txt[15:19]
print(abcd)
print(digits)
```

You can also use split the text using `txt.split("-")` and then you can extract what you want :

```
abcd = txt.split("-")[1]
digits = txt.split("-")[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please keep this post as an enquiry if it doesn't answer your question.

If what your are saying is that the string is of the form a-B-X0-c-d-X1
and that you want to extract B-X0 from the string then you can do the following:

```py
text =  'a-B-X0-c-d-X1'
extracted_val = '-'.join(text.split('-')[1:3])
```

Comment: if you were asking something else ,let me know